# How to automatically trigger button click?

Tags: jquery

I have this code to automatically trigger a click event of a button inside the function of that same button here is the HTML for the button:

```
<a class="button widget uib_w_4 d-margins icon user black"
data-uib="app_framework/button" data-ver="1" id="btnconnecter"
onclick="mycallback()"  href="" >
```

and here is the content of the `mycallback` function:

```
function mycallback(data) {
    test=false;  
    var eml = document.getElementById("tbemail").value;
    var mp = document.getElementById("tbmdp").value;

    $.each(data.user, function (i,data) 
    {
        if((data.email==eml )&&(data.mdp==mp))   
        test=true;
    });   
    if (test==true)
    {
        $("#btnconnecter").href="#acc";
        $('#btnconnecter').trigger( "click" );   
    }
    else
    intel.xdk.notification.alert("verifier votre email/mot de passe");
}
```

The problem is the click event is not triggered. What is the problem?

Comment: You're not passing an argument to `mycallback`. So `$.each(data.user, ...)` doesn't have anything to loop over, so it never sets `test = true`.

Comment: thnx ut no i amm passing i just didnt put that part the function is write it works if i simply replace the trigger by alert("hi"); for example

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a closing tag and some text.  This works in standard html. not sure if the trigger.io framework is affecting the functionality.

```
<a id="btnconnecter" onclick="mycallback()"  href="" >some text</a>
```

also, add a simple line in your function to see if the problem is that its not being called, or that the function logic is not  working.  This is always the first step to take to determine the root cause when you think your function is not being called.

```
alert("in my call back");
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery's `.click()` and `.trigger("click")` functions don't behave the way normal clicks do; they don't read the href attribute, so they can't change the page that way. The best way to get around this is to set the variable `window.location.href` to the URL you want to go to. This will cause the browser to refresh and load the requested page.

---

Notes:

I had to add my own `data` object because you didn't include on in
   the code you posted.

I removed the `onclick="callback()"` and put everything into a jQuery
   event handler, and changed the JavaScript selectors into jQuery
   selectors. This makes for shorter and more-consistent code.

---

```
$("#btnconnecter").click(function(){ 
    var data = {
        "user" : [
            {"email" : "email",
             "mdp" : "motdepasse"},
            {"email" : "email2",
             "mdp" : "motdepasse2"}           
            ]
    }
    var test = false;  
    var eml = $("#tbemail").val();
    var mp = $("#tbmdp").val();

    $.each(data.user, function(k,v) {
        if(v.email == eml && v.mdp == mp) {
            test = true;
        }
    });

    if (test == true) {
        alert("L'email et mot de passe sont corrects.");
        window.location.href = "#acc";
    } else {
        //intel.xdk.notification.alert("Verifier votre email/mot de passe.");
        alert("Verifier votre email/mot de passe.");
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/IronFlare/6xc4dff8/

Comment: thnx thats what i tried the first time  and it didnt work i even tried it again now still dnt work thats why i tried using .show() like this
 
     
      if (test == true) {
         alert("L'email et mot de passe sont corrects.");
      $("#acc").show();
      } else {
     
        alert("Verifier votre email/mot de passe.");
       }   
 
but it changes the content of the body and the header stays the same

Comment: The code that you wrote initially suggested that you want the browser to go to `http://[the url you are currently at]#acc` if the password is correct. Is that what you want or not?

Comment: yes exactly but the #acc has no html file its a subpage another dive in the same mypage.html file  i

Comment: Right. If you have a div called with the id "acc" in the page and you add "#acc" to the end of window.location.href, then the browser will scroll to that div.